# Appengine SDK 1.8.2 : Unable to view cron jobs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

When using the python SDK 1.8.2, View cron jobs page in dev_appserver admin interface return following errors :

```
Error loading cron.yaml:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/User/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/cron_handler.py", line 42, in get
   values['cronjobs'] = self._get_cron_jobs()
File "/home/User/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/cron_handler.py", line 48, in _get_cron_jobs
   cron_info = self._parse_cron_yaml()
File "/home/User/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/cron_handler.py", line 78, in _parse_cron_yaml
   with open(os.path.join(self.configuration.servers[0].application_root,
AttributeError: 'ApplicationConfiguration' object has no attribute 'servers'
```

In `SDK 1.8.1` works as expected with the same `cron.yaml`. Any setting need to change in cron.yaml when using `SDK 1.8.2` ?

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: FS Update
  url: /fs_updatemail
  schedule: every day 00:01
```

Issue : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9665

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed your cron.yaml.  The servers functionality was renamed to modules between 1.8.1 and 1.8.2.  You should have received an email indicating this and what to do.

Comment: does look like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem  also. I upgraded to SDK 1.8.3 on Windows and now I can see cron jobs on the development admin console.

Answer (score 0):

Should apply [patch](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/attachmentText?id=9665&aid=96650012000&name=cron-ui-1.8.2.1.patch&token=r6ii3e9nw3CyeTo6GjVoper22Q0%3A1382377851786) in the current GAE installation as mentioned here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9665#c12